# how to uninstall opencv-python package installed by using pip in anaconda?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I have tried to install OpenCV in anaconda. but when I use it, I figure out the instead of using OpenCV, the program using OpenCV-python and that why my program crashed.
I type "conda uninstall opencv" but it just uninstalls OpenCV package not OpenCV-python. I also use " conda uninstall opencv-python" and "pip uninstall opencv-python" but it's not work.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

@Lê Huy Hùng

Please check official documentations before posting a question like this.

Here's the [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/) of `pip uninstall`

Here's how I uninstalled it

> pip uninstall opencv-python
>
> Uninstalling opencv-python-3.4.0.12:
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtCore
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtTest
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavcodec.57.107.100.dylib
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavformat.57.83.100.dylib
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavresample.3.7.0.dylib
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.55.78.100.dylib
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libswresample.2.9.100.dylib
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libswscale.4.8.100.dylib
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/LICENSE-3RD-PARTY.txt
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/LICENSE.txt
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-35.pyc
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/**init**.py
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-35.pyc
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_eye.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalcatface_extended.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_fullbody.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_licence_plate_rus_16stages.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_lowerbody.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_profileface.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_smile.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_upperbody.xml
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv_python-3.4.0.12.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv_python-3.4.0.12.dist-info/INSTALLER
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv_python-3.4.0.12.dist-info/METADATA
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv_python-3.4.0.12.dist-info/RECORD
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv_python-3.4.0.12.dist-info/WHEEL
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv_python-3.4.0.12.dist-info/metadata.json
> /Users/name/.virtualenvs/LT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv_python-3.4.0.12.dist-info/top_level.txt
> Proceed (y/n)?
> y
> Successfully uninstalled opencv-python-3.4.0.12

Answer (score 4):

To uninstall I used this line of code and it worked,

```
    sudo pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Resulted as given:

```
Uninstalling opencv-python-4.0.0.21:   Would remove:

    c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2\*
    c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opencv_python-4.0.0.21.dist-info\* Proceed (y/n)? y   Successfully uninstalled opencv-python-4.0.0.21
```

Comment: you shouldn't need `sudo` to install or uninstall packages with `pip`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to directory where pip is installing your packages.
2. You should able to see the egg file that corresponds to the package you want to uninstall. Delete the egg file (or, to be on the safe side, move it to a different directory).
3. Do the same with the package files for the package you want to delete for (opencv-python)

Comment: i can't find  where pip is installing your packages, can you show me where is it in your computer

Comment: check in  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ or  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/), this issue must be solved quite easily:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the following code at the terminal: `pip uninstall opencv-python`. It works really well.
You can see the:
[captured screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwjvB.png)

Comment: Please include the code in the answer, don't use an external image (external links may break in the future)