# How to limit requirement packages when installing python packages using PYPI?

Tags: python, opencv, pypi, mediapipe

I intend to use mediapipe on heroku for personal assignments.

However, it doesn't seem to be able to use the opencv-python package, which is a requirement of mediapipe on heroku.

Therefore, I want to use `opencv-python-headless`, which is an opencv package available on heroku, but an error occurs because `opencv-python` has already been installed while installing mediapipe.

How can I install mediapipe without installing opencv-python?

Comment: Since `opencv-python` has already been installed, you can uninstall it using `pip uninstall opencv-python`; see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072587/how-to-uninstall-opencv-python-package-installed-by-using-pip-in-anaconda. Next you can install the headless version using `opencv-python-headless`

Comment: I've been thinking about that method too.
However, I couldn't install opencv-python and opencv-python-headless together because heroku's max slug size is set at 500MB.
My slug size is already large enough, so if you install opencv-python and opencv-python-headless together, I can't push first.

Comment: sudo apt update and sudo pip3 opencv-python-headless

Comment: @supra, no. you cant sudo on heroku. all pip things have to go through a requirements.txt there.

Comment: @GBG You **don't** have to install both together. First uninstall `opencv-python`, then install `opencv-python-headless`

Comment: @Jeru Luke, good idea. but does not work on that platform, since you cannot even call pip directly (again, it's all supposed to be handled from requirements.txt

Comment: @Jeru Luke, I understand what you are saying.
But it is heroku build pack that installs the package from heroku build, not me.
So I can't control the install order of python packages and I can't uninstall `opencv-python` until the build is complete.
Besides, after the heroku build is done, it seems impossible to remove only certain packages.

Comment: @GBG and berak sorry I am helpless here. I've never used Heroku before.

Comment: @GBG, pythonanywhere.com might be a hosting alternative (much more liberal)

Comment: @berak, thanks  I'll consider that method as well.

Comment: [linl]https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python-headless/  and [link]https://libraries.io/pypi/opencv-contrib-python/4.5.5.64

Comment: Then do pip install opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.64